# Size error on read file

Tags: c++

**RESOLVED**

I'm trying to make a simple file loader.
I aim to get the text from a shader file (plain text file) into a char* that I will compile later.

I've tried this function:

```
char* load_shader(char* pURL)
{
    FILE *shaderFile;
    char* pShader;

    // File opening
    fopen_s( &shaderFile, pURL, "r" );
    if ( shaderFile == NULL )
        return "FILE_ER";

    // File size
    fseek (shaderFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    int lSize = ftell (shaderFile);
    rewind (shaderFile);

    // Allocating size to store the content
    pShader = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * lSize);
    if (pShader == NULL)
    {
        fputs ("Memory error", stderr); 
        return "MEM_ER";
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    int result = fread (pShader, sizeof(char), lSize, shaderFile);
    if (result != lSize)
    {
        // size of file 106/113
        cout << "size of file " << result << "/" << lSize << endl;
        fputs ("Reading error", stderr);
        return "READ_ER";
    }

    // Terminate
    fclose (shaderFile);
    return 0;

}
```

But as you can see in the code I have a strange size difference at the end of the process which makes my function crash.

I must say I'm quite a beginner in C so I might have missed some subtilities regarding the memory allocation, types, pointers...
**How can I solve this size issue?**

**EDIT 1:*

First, I shouldn't return 0 at the end but pShader; that seemed to be what crashed the program.
Then, I change the type of reult to size_t, and added a end character to pShader, adding pShdaer[result] = '/0'; after its declaration so I can display it correctly.
Finally, as @JamesKanze suggested, I turned fopen_s into fopen as the previous was not usefull in my case.

Comment: @Rems variable `int result` should be type `size_t` not `int`. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: If you're going with c++ and streams, go full c++ and use `filestream`s. :)

Comment: *How can I solve this size issue?* use C++, not C: use std::ifstream and std::string for instance - it will fix a number of issues with this code, like the file not being closed in one of your early return statements

Comment: @rems btw, why are you returning `NULL` at the end of the fuction? Shouldn't you be returning `pShader` instead? Also, your function leaks the open file descriptor if the allocation fails. Furthermore, you should **really really really** be using `std::ifstream` and `std::string` for file handling in C++.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I'll have to use std::ifstream! I'll get into that. BTW, @TheParamagneticCroissant return 0 at the end is a mistake.

Comment: how big is the file, and can you give us the exact result

Comment: And FYI, I found this code in the example of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/, so maybe, if its examples are THAT strange, I will try to avoid this website.
Thanks, let me experiment with ifstream, I'll be back in a minute!

Comment: @sp2danny, `// size of file 106/113`

Comment: @Rems have you strictly followed that code(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)? or missing something?

Comment: The file is pretty little, just a really basic Vertex Shader that does nothing particular. Its size is 113 bytes.

Comment: the only error i see is that if the filesize wont fit in an int, but that aint it. i think your error happen *after* this function

Comment: @sp2danny 113 bytes value should fit in `int`.

Comment: I'll disagree with the previous comments about `std::filebuf` (and the interfaces `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` that use it).  In this case, you're doing something so low level that you really should use the system interfaces directly.  Streams (both C++ and C) introduce a lot of additional functionality (and complexity) which you don't need.

Comment: Using an `int` for the results of `ftell` is dangerous, but given the values he's cited (106 and 113), I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Ok, the error was _after_, as mentionned @sp2danny. I tried to print the output value using a cout... But the output was empty as I returned 0. So NOW I can print the file BUT I have strange char at the end of the char*:
#version 150

in vec2 position;

void main()
{
 gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}========²²² ... and so on. So I suppose it came from the fact that malloc allocates 113 bytes where I fill only 106 with fread?

Comment: And `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.  That's a fundamental invariant in C and C++.

Comment: if you are going to print it as a c-style string, allocate one extra byte, and append 0 to the end

Comment: `fopen_s` is an _optional_ extension to the C library, not always present.  And there's no point in using it (rather than `fopen`) if you're not going to check the return value; `fopen` is cleaner.  (For that matter, I don't really see the point of `fopen_s`; unlike most of the `_s` functions, it doesn't really provide any additional safety with regards to `fopen`.)

Comment: This seems very strange. Have you tried to read another file?

Comment: @JamesKanze Ok, VS suggested that change when I was using fopen, but I changed it back.

Comment: Eerything works well now, thanks!
I'll try to use strems though, for a better c++ oriented code.

Comment: @sp2danny I think you should write an answer summing all your advices so it'll be more clear for future visitors (if there are any).

Comment: By the way, where is the C / C++ code there? I would say it's mostly C, but apparently I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for this sort of raw access, you're probably better off
using the system level functions: `CreateFile` or `open`,
`ReadFile` or `read` and `CloseHandle` or `close`, with
`GetFileSize` or `stat` to get the size.  Using `FILE*` or
`std::filebuf` will only introduce an additional level of
buffering and processing, for no gain in your case.

As to what you are seeing: there is no guarantee that an `ftell`
will return anything exploitable as a numeric value; it could
very well be just a magic cookie.  On most current systems, it
*is* a byte offset into the physical file, but on any non-Unix
system, the offset into the physical file will not map directly
to the logical file you are reading unless you open the file in
binary mode.  If you use `"rb"` to open the file, you'll
probably see the same values.  (Theoretically, you could get
extra 0's at the end of the file, but practically, the OS's
where that happened are either extinct, or only used on legacy
mainframes.)

EDIT:

Since the answer stating this has been deleted: you should loop
on the `fread` until it returns 0 (setting `errno` to 0 before
each call, and checking it after the return to see whether the
function returned because of an error or because it reached the
end of file).  Having said this: if you're on one of the usual
Windows or Unix systems, and the file is local to the machine,
and not too big, `fread` will read it all in one go.  The
difference in size you are seeing (given the numerical values
you posted) is almost certainly due to the fact that the two
byte Windows line endings are being mapped to a single `'\n'`
character.  To avoid this, you must open in binary mode;
alternatively, if you really are dealing with text (and want
this mapping), you can just ignore the extra bytes in your
buffer, setting the `'\0'` terminator after the last byte
actually read.